# Vue-cli 3: how to use static assets with determined path?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

My app has address:

```
https:/firstpath.com/firstsubfolder/app.html
```

Using relative paths my static assets go to:

```
https:/firstpath.com/firstsubfolder/img/image.png
```

How can I use a determined path for my static assets instead? For example:

```
https:/secondpath.com/secondsubfolder/thirdsubfolder/img/image.png
```

Comment: Can you post some template code that you use? From one of your comments below, I noticed that you are using `<img :src="require('https://....')" />` I think just using it as `<img :src="\`https://..../${item.image}\`" />` is what you want. Also, there should be two slashes after `https://`

Comment: @ChiragRavindra Sorry, in fact the code is exactly as you described. I lust missed one slash and the editor turns backticks into a quote in the answer

Answer (score 0):

If your assets are on `https://secondpath.com/secondsubfolder/thirdsubfolder`
But if your app is on another domain, you just have to call your assets with full URL for each one.

If you application URL is `https://firstdomain.com/firstapp/app.html` there you'll be able to call assets from `https://fristdomain.com/anotherdir/assets.js` for example.

Comment: I use address as: <img :src="require(`../assets/${item.image}.png)`> If I change it to: <img :src="require(`https:/secondpath.com/secondsubfolder/thirdsubfolder/img/${item.image}.png)`> Webpack fail to compile my app

Comment: I think you should concatenate it with quotes : `require('https://secondpath.com/secondsubfolder/thirdsubfolder/img/'+${item.image}+'.png')` the concatenate char depends on the file type you are in (+ is for JS)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using vue cli3 just set the `assetsdir` property in your vue.config.js.
More info is available at https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#assetsdir

Comment: Thank you, it's defenitely the right way but I'm still suffering with it. I'm playing around vue.config.js and that is what I came up with (doesn't work):
`module.exports = {
    publicPath: "./",
    assetsDir: "../../secondpath.com/secondsubfolder/thirdsubfolder/img/"
  }`
The problem is that this path is relative to my outputDir (dist by default) and I still can't set an absolute path to my static assets

Comment: Because the asset path is on another domain i would recommend to use an absolut path like `https://secondpath.com/...` and then everything should work. At least i hope so ;)